# InvalidCastException in Template Xamarin.Forms Shell Apps

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin, mono

When starting a template Xamarin.Forms Shell app, I get the following exception as the app is starting up:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2673
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ExpressionEvaluator.TargetObjectToExpression(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ExpressionEvaluator.cs:line 87
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 474
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 1545
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValue(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 96
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2673
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ExpressionEvaluator.TargetObjectToExpression(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ExpressionEvaluator.cs:line 87
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 474
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 1545
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValue(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 96
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'.
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.TargetObjectToObject(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 2673
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ExpressionEvaluator.TargetObjectToExpression(EvaluationContext ctx, Object obj) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ExpressionEvaluator.cs:line 87
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 474
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.CreateObjectValueImpl(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\SoftDebuggerAdaptor.cs:line 1545
   at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.CreateObjectValue(EvaluationContext ctx, IObjectValueSource source, ObjectPath path, Object obj, ObjectValueFlags flags) in C:\A\1\216\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line 96
```

This segment of the log immediately precededed several lines related to hot reloading, so taking the hint I disabled that feature and the exception does not occur.  So it's definitely related, but that still doesn't tell me what is actually going on.

I am running Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012, and Xamarin.Essentials 1.6.1.  This occurs in both the tabbed and flyout templates.

So far as I can tell, this does not affect app functionality, and hot reloading still works.  I am mostly just curious as to what's going on, and if there is anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: What is the version of Visual Studio? try to update the latest version, create new blank xamarin.shell project, build again.

Comment: I am running v16.9.4 there, I believe that is the latest as of this post?

Comment: It may also perhaps be relevant to note that this is running in the emulator, targeting Android SDK 28.

Comment: try to target other device to test, Emulator android 8.1 or real device.